# Scala Singleton comparison with Java

Tags: java, scala

So I understand in Scala you can't have static members but instead we use a Singleton (don't fully get this concept yet though). So I am assuming a code like this in Scala

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
//Making use of Singleton: companion Object & Class

class CheckSumAccumulator {
  private var sum = 0
  def add(b: Byte) { sum += b }
  def checksum(): Int = ~(sum & 0xFF) + 1
}

object CheckSumAccumulator{
  private val cache = Map[String, Int]()

  def calc(s: String): Int =
    if (cache.contains(s))
      cache(s)
    else {
      val acc = new CheckSumAccumulator
      for (c <- s)
        acc.add(c.toByte)
      val cs = acc.checksum()
      cache += (s -> cs)
      cs
    }
}
```

will have an equivalent like this in Java:

```
public class CheckSumAccumulator {
    private var sum = 0
    static void add(byte b){
        ...
    }

    static int checksum(){
        ...
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        private val cache = ...

        def calc(String s){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is my way of thinking right? I'm learning Scala :)

Answer (score 4):

That's vaguely correct. Since objects have distinct types (and are not technically always actual singletons), they get compiled to a separate class. Objects can have the same name as a class in the same package. Such object / class or object / trait pairs are called companions and each has access to other's private members. Because of this, objects have their names mangled by having a `$` added to the end. There are also special static forwarding methods are added to companion class so from the Java world it appears the objects members are static members of the class.

The reason objects are not strictly always singletons is that if they're nested (directly or indirectly) within a trait or class, then every instance of that class bears its own version of the object and then there are as many of the objects as there are instances of the enclosing trait(s) / class(es). Because Scala has path-dependent types, each of those objects has a type distinct from all others.